# Plone2pdf --- export to pdf in Plone

Tags: python, plone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate PDF from Plone content types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570322/generate-pdf-from-plone-content-types)

I am trying to enable export to pdf option in plone ?

Do we have any option in plone for doing that ?

Say, for example I am having a document, which I can print, view in full screen, mail it to a friend and similarly can I export that document to pdf ?

Doing a little research on this, I found that we can export the plone news to pdf using plone2pdf. I am taking the correct path or am I missing something here ?

--Sabs

Comment: There's an identical question already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570322/generate-pdf-from-plone-content-types/7570685#7570685

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

Use print as pdf file in your browser

Testing addons like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.sendaspdf